# Target multiple fiels with focusOut jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a function to real-time get the final price but i have multiple input field that can be seperately filled in.

This is the script i have

```
$('.checkout-contant').focusout(function () {
    var contant = $('.checkout-contant').val();
    var pin = $('.checkout-pin').val();
    var creditcard = $('.checkout-creditcard').val();
    var waardebon = $('.checkout-waardebon').val();

    var totalprice = $('.total.final-price.price').text();
    var newprice = Number(totalprice.replace(/\,/g,'.')) - Number(contant.replace(/\,/g,'.')) - Number(pin.replace(/\,/g,'.')) - Number(creditcard.replace(/\,/g,'.')) - Number(waardebon.replace(/\,/g,'.'));

    $('.resterend-price').val("€ " + newprice.toFixed(2));
});
```

This works. But i need to have the code for every payment option, if a customer wants to pay with only pin and fills in that he pays 900 with pin and focus out of the pin input field this code should also be ran.

Kind of like this:

```
$('.checkout-contant', '.checkout-pin', '.checkout-creditcard', '.checkout-waardebon').focusout(function () {
    var contant = $('.checkout-contant').val();
    var pin = $('.checkout-pin').val();
    var creditcard = $('.checkout-creditcard').val();
    var waardebon = $('.checkout-waardebon').val();

    var totalprice = $('.total.final-price.price').text();
    var newprice = Number(totalprice.replace(/\,/g,'.')) - Number(contant.replace(/\,/g,'.')) - Number(pin.replace(/\,/g,'.')) - Number(creditcard.replace(/\,/g,'.')) - Number(waardebon.replace(/\,/g,'.'));

    $('.resterend-price').val("€ " + newprice.toFixed(2));
});
```

But this doesn't work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The selector needs to be one string, like this...

```
$('.checkout-contant, .checkout-pin, .checkout-creditcard, .checkout-waardebon').focusout(
  ...
);
```

Comment: You're right, thanks! This works. Will approve this answer within the limit of 10 minutes.